# How to move stored procedures from one DB to another DB

Tags: sql-server-2008

Could any one explain me how can we move all the stored procedures from one DB to another.

Answer (score 3):

One of

- Script them from SSMS (right click, script wizard)
- Import/Export wizard in SSMS
- A 3rd party tool like Red Gate SQL Compare
- ...

Comment: I need to write Stored procedure for that.

Answer (score 2):

you can generate a script with all the store procedure you need to move then you can run that script against the new database

- Right click on your DataBaseNode-->Task-->Generate Script

it runs a wizard the will help you to script all the object your need: you can select the store procedure you want to copy over. At the end you can specify to generate the script into the clipboard so you just need open a query window on the destination database and run the generated script

Comment: I need to write Stored Procedure for that

Comment: I don't know what you need to to but if you need to schedule this task or make it "runnable" it would be better create a SQL job.
Anyway you can create the script and stick it into a store proc